# C# - The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

Tags: c#

I am just learning c#. I am trying to make simple CRUD in c# windows form but got some error there. The error says `The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.`
Below code shows how i have tried.

**App.config** for connection with `SQL SERVER`

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="connectionstr" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-F8UCLUB;Initial Catalog=bug_tracker;Integrated Security=True" />
```

**DBConnection** class

```
class DBConnection
{
    private string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstr"].ConnectionString;

    public SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            return connection;
        }
    }
}
```

Function to insert

```
 public void Insert(Programmer t)
    {
        conn.Open();
        IDbTransaction trans = null;

        try
        {
            conn.BeginTransaction();

            SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(null, conn);
            sql.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_programmer VALUES(@fullName, @username, @password)";
            sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullName", t.FullName);
            sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", t.Username);
            sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", t.Password);

            sql.Prepare();
            sql.ExecuteNonQuery();

            trans.Commit();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The ConnectionString property has not been initialized after "using"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420160/the-connectionstring-property-has-not-been-initialized-after-using)

Comment: Your `GetConnection()` method disposes the connection when it returns.

Comment: how do i solve it then

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The problem is `using` keyword.  `using` directive only be use
>   disposable objects.
>
> If you create any instance in using block, the instance disposible out
>   of curly braces..

```
 public SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)                
                connection.Open();

            return connection;            
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `SqlConnection` Object get disposed since you're using it inside the `using` which calls `Dispose()` on it.

And if you're going to return something, it must not be disposed, It has to stay in memory.

If you wanna have more understanding of how this works then i'll try my best :

> The return statement returns back the address of the Object, then later
>   `dispose()` get called on that object, by now that address doesn't
>   hold that Object anymore, therefor that exception is thrown.

Comment: Disposing something does in no way remove it from memory.

Comment: What does it do then ? Other than exposing the Object to the `GC` to be released.